# How to run nodejs without command prompt in windows?

Tags: windows, node.js

I have tried the nodejs with command prompt. And it is working fine. How can i try to nodejs output without command prompt in windows platform.

Comment: What do you mean? You can see the web pages in the web browser and code in any text editor you want.

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Do you want to run Node.js as a service?

Comment: Check out [runbg module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runbg) on npm.

Answer (score 18):

I assume you want to run Node.js as a service. You can use nssm: http://nssm.cc/

```
nssm.exe install sydjs-node c:\where-i-put-node-standalone\node.exe c:\code\SydJS\server.js
net start sydjs-node
```

Solution found here (I don't use node on windows =) ):
http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2011/03/16/node-js-on-windows/