# How to get back to the command line

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I am writing a **batch** file to install packages and run server for multiple `Node.js` applications. My current script start the first server and then do nothing.

I think it is due to `node server` command. It's change the **command line** to **node console** and then can't run the other commands. So I need to get back to the **command line** from the **node console**.

I need to install packages and run the first server and then install packages and run the second server and then another server.

My current script:

```
@echo off
title App Installer
echo Starting Deployment: %date% %time%
pushd app-svc
echo Installing Service...
call npm install
node server
popd
pushd app-view
echo Installing UI...
call npm install
popd
pushd app-view/public
echo Installing Public UI...
call npm install
popd
node server
popd
pushd app-admin
echo Installing App Admin...
call npm install
echo Building App Admin...
call npm run client:build
echo Running App Admin...
call npm run serve:dev
```

Also I need to close the command prompt after all these commands without stopping the server.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Would running a cmd window minimized be an option?

Comment: @geisterfurz007 No. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8504680/6707985 might help? Looks like something that suits what I think you might need. Other than that I cannot provide anything else... Good luck!

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Thanks for your effort. I'll check this.

Comment: [start /min <cmd>](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Windows batch file commands asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449188/running-windows-batch-file-commands-asynchronously)